# Working with delegates synchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

In the below code, `self.theFiles` prints the `null`. Because after calling `[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"]`, `getFiles` method keeps working.

I want `getFiles` method to wait until `[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"]` finishes to get file list and put the data to `self.theFiles` object. But after `[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"]`, `getFiles` keeps working.

```
@synthesize theFiles;

- (void)getFiles:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
    }
    NSLog(self.theFiles); //Prints null
    NSLog(@"Finished");
}

#pragma mark DBRestClientDelegate methods

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    NSArray* validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txt", @"text", nil];
    NSMutableArray* newPhotoPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
        self.theFiles=child.path;
        NSString* extension = [[child.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
        if (!child.isDirectory && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound) {
            [newPhotoPaths addObject:child.path];
        }
    }

    NSLog(self.theFiles); //Prints the file list
}
```

Output:

```
null
Finished
/file1.txt
/file2.txt
..... the file list in my dropbox
```

Is it possible to work my getFiles method with delegate synchronously?

**UPDATE**

I updated my code. I want to lock the thread using `NSLock` but doesn't work. The same result.

```
@synthesize theFiles;

- (void)getFiles:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    }
    else
    {
       if ([self.theLock tryLock]) {
        [self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/"];
        NSLog(self.theFiles); //Prints null
        NSLog(@"Finished");
       }
    }

}

#pragma mark DBRestClientDelegate methods

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    NSArray* validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txt", @"text", nil];
    NSMutableArray* newPhotoPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
        self.theFiles=child.path;
        NSString* extension = [[child.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
        if (!child.isDirectory && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound) {
            [newPhotoPaths addObject:child.path];
        }
    }

    NSLog(self.theFiles); //Prints the file list
    [self.theLock unlock];
}
```

Comment: Well one thing you *could* do is set up an `NSLock` object which you lock after you call that method and unlock in the delegate, but what would be the point?  You want to avoid blocking threads and that is why this pattern exists in the first place.

Comment: Then is it possible to create new thread and make this in second thread without blocking the whole app? I just want to know what I need?

Comment: What you need is to write your application in a way that accounts for this asynchronicity. You're only going to be making things hard on yourself by trying to force this synchronicity on an asynchronous process.

Comment: I guess the best way is GCD for making this, right?

Comment: blocks, gcd, delegate: the latter you already have.

Comment: updated my answer. can you look?

Comment: you protected part of `getFiles:` from executing with different threads at the same time, the next thread calling `getFiles:` will wait until the thread running the protected part of `getFiles:` receives unlock at the delegate method (which must be executed on this thread, but it is a conventional thing about delegates anyway).

Comment: but the result is still the same.. I am very confused about what am I supposed to do?. Can you suggest me a tutorial or give me an example?